# Compare the output of sstream with initial value

Tags: c++

writing the code I had following difficulty:
I have templated class where I initialize template type array. 
Then in main method i create different generics objects of the class and depending on on users choice use one of them.
Afterwards user can add values to be stored in array.
But if I create char instance of the class "HashTable  charTable;" 
and then in following method

```
  template <class T>
T HashTable<T>::insertValue()
{

    T value;
    string str;
    cout << "Insert value please" << endl;
    getline(cin,str);
    stringstream convert(str);

    if(convert >> value){

    return value;

    }throw type_e;


}
```

and insert "2b" for a char -it takes only first char and than return it to store in array.
What I want to do is to check if string  that was inputed and converted value have the same amount of characters inside,and throw an exception if  not.
Do you have any suggestions to do that?
Thanx

Comment: Suggestion: isolate the tasks the shall be done in your program. Isolate input processing from data management. Define a clear design what shall be done in which component. When you have isolated them you are able to solve the problem or ask a more specific question.

Comment: `"2b"` is a `string` not a `char`.

Comment: yes but if user wants to add 2b instead of type just char- array will store "2"-while i want it to throw an exception

Comment: Your not going to get many more answers on here if you don't start **accepting** some of the answer that you have gotten.

Answer (score 0):

Use template specialization and create a version just for `char`. In this version `throw` an exception given the condition `if(str.size() > 1)`.

An alternative is after you extract the value and you expect all the data to be read with that, then throw an exception if this condition is true again.

```
if(convert >> value) {
    T dummy;
    if(convert >> dummy) throw type_e;
    return value;
}
```